# VueJS Modal component inside component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component like this:

```
<test></test>
```

I declare this as follows:

```js
Vue.component('test', {
  data: {
    showModal: true
  },
  methods: {
    displayComponentModalDialog: function() {
      this.showModal = true;
    }
  },
  template: `<button @click='displayComponentModalDialog'>test</button>`
});
```

The `<test></test>` component is then placed somewhere inside the `<div id="#app">` wrapper.

```
var app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  // etc.    
})
```

Now, I want to display another component inside the test component. So in this case I want a dialog to appear after I click the button in test component. I am not able to achieve this.

What I did is adding a new component:

```
Vue.component('dialog', {
  template: '#dialog-template'
});
```

And then the following code, although I do not know for sure where to put it.

```html
<!-- template for the modal component -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="dialog-template">
  <transition name="dialog">
    <div class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
              default header
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <slot name="body">
              default body
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="$emit('close')">
                OK
              </button>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</script>
<!-- use the modal component, pass in the prop -->
<dialog v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
  <h3 slot="header">header</h3>
  <p slot="body">
    test
  </p>
</dialog>
```

I tried putting this code inside the `<test></test>` but doesn't work. If I put it inside the template attribute in the component structure, it complains about only one root element.

So it is clear I miss some basic conception how this actually works in VueJS. Someone can help me clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Is is a method inside the test component            

    displayComponentModalDialog: function() {
    this.showModal = true;
    },

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see your component indeed doesn't have a root tag. Templates have to have a root tag.

This is NOT a valid Vue template:

```
<div>
    <h1>Stuff</h1>
</div>
<h2>Other stuff</h2>
```

This IS a valid Vue template:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>Stuff</h1>
    </div>
    <h2>Other stuff</h2>
</div>
```

Note that in the second version we have a single root element for the template, a `<div>`, whereas in the first one we do not.

You have both a `<script></script>` and a `<dialog></dialog>` in your component template.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add another component in your `test` component . you can use `slot` on it.

You can refer to this documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Example:

```
//component 1
<template>
  <div id="modal">
    // do something for your modal here.

    <slot></slot> // reserve area for your another html or component.
  </div>
  
</template>

// component 2
<template>
   <your-modal-component>
     <another-component>
   </your-modal-component>
</template>
```